# Cokernel of a differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $X = C^n(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, $Y=X = C^{n-1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with $n$ as high as neccessary, and define $D : X\times X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ by
$$D(\alpha,\beta)=(\alpha'+ \beta, \alpha + \beta')$$

I am interested in its kernel and cokernel. The kernel is easy to see: If $D(\alpha,\beta)=0$, one has that $\alpha'= -\beta$ and $\beta'=-\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha''=\alpha$, so the kernel is the two-dimensional span
$$\langle \cosh,\sinh\rangle$$

But what about its cokernel? I do not see how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I figured something out: Applying the Laplace transform to each component of
$$ (\alpha'(t)+\beta(t), \alpha(t)+\beta'(t)) = (f,g) \hspace{2cm}(*)$$

yields (assuming all tansformed functions exist) \begin{align}s\hat{\alpha}(s) - \alpha_0 + \hat{\beta}(s) &= \hat{f}(s)\\ \hat\alpha(s) + s\hat\beta(s)-\beta_0 &= \hat g(s),\end{align}

so solving the first equation for $\hat\beta$ and plugging this into the second equation means that
\begin{align} \hat\alpha(s) + s(\hat f(s) - s\hat\alpha(s) +\alpha_0 ) - \beta_0 &= \hat g(s)\\
\Leftrightarrow\hat\alpha(s) &= \frac{\hat g(s)- s\hat f(s) - s\alpha_0+\beta_0}{1-s^2}\end{align}

So using the inverse Laplace transform, one gets a solution $(\alpha,\beta)$ to $(*)$ for each choice of $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$, so $D$ is surjective and has empty cokernel.

Of course one has to be careful whether or not all of those transformed functions actually exist, but for me it is okay to restrict myself to $C^{n}(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$.